# Using same control instance in different views of an ASP.net MultiView

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have an asp:MultiView control with two views and two UserControls.
In the first view I want to put every control in a different tab of an ASPxTabControl.
In the second view I want to display the two controls continiously, one after another.

How can I achieve that in every view is used/seen the same control instance with exact the same viewstates when I switch between the views?

Or is there even a better way instead of using a MutliView?

Thank you very much in advance for your reply.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your ASPX page:

```
    <asp:MultiView ID="mvTest" ActiveViewIndex="0" runat="server">
        <asp:View ID="vwFirst" runat="server">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phFirstContainer" runat="server" ></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="vwSecond" runat="server">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phSecondContainer" runat="server" ></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSwitchViews" Text="Switch Views" OnClick="btnSwitchViews_Click"/>
```

And this on your ASPX.CS code-behind page:

```
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myControl = new Label() {ID = "MyTextControl"};

        if (mvTest.GetActiveView().ID == "vwFirst")
        {
            myControl.Text = "I'm the same controller on the first view";
            phFirstContainer.Controls.Add(myControl);
        }
        else if(mvTest.GetActiveView().ID == "vwSecond")
        {
            myControl.Text = "I'm the same controller on the second view";
            phSecondContainer.Controls.Add(myControl);
        }
    }

    protected void btnSwitchViews_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mvTest.ActiveViewIndex = mvTest.ActiveViewIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
```

I'm using an ASP.NET Label for simplicity, but you can easily use a user control by instantiating it programatically using the type of the user controls in question.